# what's the data latency of graph teams api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I am getting user activity usage data at

```
6/2/2020
```

, it's still empty, and the time for now is

```
Wed, 03 Jun 2020 16:22:20 GMT
```

**API:**

[reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0)

query by date

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fount a precise answer to this question when I encountered it myself.

The only relevant info I found in the documentation from Microsoft is this:

> Reports are available for the last 7 days, 30 days, 90 days, and 180 days. Data won't exist for all reporting periods right away. The reports become available within 48 hours.

[Link to the documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/activity-reports?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fActivity-Reports-in-the-Office-365-admin-center-0d6dfb17-8582-4172-a9a9-aed798150263&view=o365-worldwide)

In my experience, it might take even a bit longer when the O365 account is new. But generally, 48 hours is a good approximation for how long it takes to view a report in the admin center and before it gets available via MS Graph API.